# Timeout issues with IIS/WCF services

Tags: .net, visual-studio, web-services, iis, load-testing

I'm having some timeout issues with my WCF services.

I've been doing load-testing on my web-application (silverlight). The test-scenario involves making a few WCF service calls (services are hosted locally on the IIS). I'm doing a step load-test where I start with one user and add a new user each minute. It runs fine until about 20 minutes when the tests starts failing - timeout errors start flooding in. The test-results looks like this:

[image: Load Test Results]

The red line at bottom right shows the % processor time, at about 20 minutes it drops. The graph at the bottom left shows time it takes to complete each test, and it is around 300s when the tests starts failing. The red line at top left shows number of users.

After 20 min it seems like the IIS stops handling any requests (explains why the % processor time drops). After I've run the test I have to restart the web server node in the IIS in order to get the IIS to handle incoming requests again.

I've tried maxing the throttle settings on the IIS and configured web-services open/close/send/recieve timeouts to be 60 minutes. It does not affect the results. Anyone know what could be causing these timeouts?

Comment: This might lead you to more clues..
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madhuponduru/archive/2006/05/18/601458.aspx

Comment: Definitely need more info on request per second and response times for pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It in not possible to categorically state what the issue is from these stats. How many requests per second where you getting?

Try starting the test at 10 users and increase by 2 virtual users/min and see if the test still stops at 20 virtual users.
If so, it would indicate something about the resources your virtual users are taking up.

However, given that the CPU is essentially maxed at four virtual users, it would appear that running the test on the web service host machine is less than ideal.

I would not expect 20 virtual users to max out any resources, but 20 virtual users should be enough to flat line your dev machine when it is hosting the web services and running the load test.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The issue seems to be with how we Route incoming messages (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725247/wcf-service-routing-a-bottleneck).